# How to remove scratches from LEGO windshield parts?

Tags: cleaning

I was storing my windshields from cars with other my bricks. Now they are scratched, nearly not transparent just translucent. Is there a way to sanitize transparent parts from scratches?

Comment: I'm not so sure if it's as easy as 'cleaning' the windshield. A scratch leaves a lasting physical mark on the brick.

Comment: Never tried this on LEGO, but I used to build plastic model kits and you can get a purpose made kit of micro mesh pads which you can use to essentially gently sand the scratches off. This works very well on see through plastic windows, but I'm not sure what would happen if your window was tinted.

Comment: peanut butter and toothpaste. rub them onto the windshield, and then wipe of and wash with water and soap. (the soap doesnt really matter, it will just get the smell off) that solution works for most scratches, i think it works for plastic. ;)

Comment: You can carefully use a lighter to gently melt the plastic, but I would only use this as a last resort.

Answer (score 4):

Haven't tried this with Lego, but here are the first two things that come to mind.

Novus plastic cleaners (they make 3 solutions for various scratch depths, with Lego I would probably buy the one for the finest scratches) work well on my pinball machine plastics.

About the transparency, I would try the standard headlight cleaning solutions for a car.

Comment: While we prefer tested solutions, a brief Google does show that Novus could be a good fit for the polycarbonate plastic that is used in transparent elements :)

Answer (score 4):

You've got three different approaches: 1) products that fill the scratch, 2) products that essentially dissolve the plastic material so that it re-hardens smooth, 3) products that help you polish the scratch away.

1. A silicon-based lens cleaner can do this and works for small scratches or some "cloudiness", but it won't be perfect. For example [Bausch & Lomb](http://www.northernsafety.com/Product/4190/Bausch-Lomb-Sight-Savers-Large-Disposable-Lens-Cleaning-Station-with-Silicone-Spray) or [a furniture polish with wax](http://www.ehow.com/video_4791118_remove-scratches-plastic.html).
2. It is likely that the Novus and similar products fall into this category, but they rely on polishing for the finish... similar to CD or DVD repair.
3. Here is [a step-by-step method](http://www.ehow.com/how_5013183_remove-scratches-polycarbonate-lenses.html) using household toothpaste.